# Automated installation of QGIS

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2

I need command line syntax that allows for automated/unattended installation of QGIS via System Center Configuration Manager [SCCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Configuration_Manager).

Comment: Which operating system are you working with? Windows?

Comment: SCCM is Windows

Comment: Is this more of an SCCM question?